# Rails 3 not able to connect to remote DB with mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-connection, mysql2

1. I have 2 environments: `development` and `development_with_production_data`.
2. The environments only differ in their `database.yml` entries:

   ```
   development:
     host: 127.0.0.1
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     database: [REDACTED]_development
     username: root
     password:
     pool: 5

   development_with_production_data:
     host: [REDACTED]
     port: [REDACTED]
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     database: [REDACTED]_production
     username: [REDACTED]
     password: [REDACTED]
     pool: 5
   ```
3. I have verified that the values I have `[REDACTED]` above are the correct values. I have a gui that can connect just fine and a rails 2 app that connects with the same `[REDACTED]` values.
4. Loading up and working on the `development` environment work perfect, locally.
5. Loading up and working on the `development_with_production_data` environment will not even anything but static, cached pages. No error messages, no timeouts, nothing. All I see is this:

   ```
   coneybeare $ rails s -e development_with_production_data
   NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
   Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256
   .
   => Booting WEBrick
   => Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development_with_production_data on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   => Call with -d to detach
   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
   [2011-05-09 01:23:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
   [2011-05-09 01:23:48] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [i686-darwin10]
   [2011-05-09 01:23:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3854 port=3000
   ```
6. I am using `rails 3.0.7` and have tried both `mysql2 0.3.2` and `mysql2 0.2.7`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by updating my ruby to 1.9.2 on my mac using RVM. Then I had to reinstall the bundle gem, rails gem, and do a bundle install. Previously I had been using 1.8.7 and for some reason, it was causing the hang.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mysql2 0.2.x because there is some issues with mysql2 0.3.x in rails 3.0.7

Comment: Thanks, I did try that too (should have mentioned it) but the same problem occurred. gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'. Also everything works fine when connecting to localhost

Comment: Oh, I see ..sometimes Rails throws unknown WTFs :)